# QPropertyAnimation reject to begin immediately after start() call

Tags: c++, qt, animation

See code below. I have a button that starts the animation. The problem is that i see the animation only after SECOND button press. But when animation starts, i notice that it actually have been going since FIRST button press, because it starts from a moment = `[the time between 1 and 2 button press]`.

The code: (sorry for overkill boost::shared_ptr)

**WinWin.h**:

```
#define LOGCOUT(x) { std::cout << __FILE__ << ":" << __LINE__ << " " << x << "\n"; }

class WinWin: public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        Q_PROPERTY(unsigned animprop READ getAnimProp WRITE setAnimProp);

        WinWin();
        unsigned getAnimProp();
        void setAnimProp(unsigned);

    protected:
        virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *);

    public slots:
        void slotButtonClicked();

    private:
        unsigned m_anim_prop;
        QPropertyAnimation *m_animation;
        QPushButton *m_button;
};
```

**WinWin.cpp**:

```
WinWin::WinWin()
: m_anim_prop(0)
{
    m_animation = new QPropertyAnimation(this, "animprop");
    m_button = new QPushButton(this);
    m_button->setText( "Start" );
    m_button->move ( 40, 40 );
    m_button->resize( 100, 30 );
    m_button->show();

    resize( 640, 480 );
    connect( m_button.get(), SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(slotButtonClicked()) );
}

unsigned WinWin::getAnimProp()
{

}

void WinWin::setAnimProp(unsigned _prop)
{
    LOGCOUT("anim " << _prop);
    m_anim_prop = _prop;
    update();
}

void WinWin::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    QPainter painter( this );
    painter.setPen( QColor(0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff) );
    painter.drawLine( 0, 0, width(), m_anim_prop );
}

void WinWin::slotButtonClicked()
{
    m_animation->setDuration( 1000 * 4 );
    m_animation->setStartValue( 0 );
    m_animation->setEndValue( height() );
    m_animation->setLoopCount( -1 ); // infinite number of loops

    // Fire!
    m_animation->start();

    LOGCOUT( m_animation->state() ); // says: 2
}
```

**main.cpp**:

```
int main ( int argc, char **argv )
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    WinWin winwin;
    winwin.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: @KubaOber but does the QObject will be deleted automatically if is has no parent? For example, QPropertyAnimation has no parent. It knows about `this`, but this is not its parent. It is just an object that should be notified on animation ticks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, it's broken with unsigned integer types. Just use signed integer. This is probably a bug, and it seems to exist in both Qt 4.8 and 5.1. It is fixed in Qt 5.5 at least.

The code below shows how it could be minimally done in Qt 5.1. Due to the use of `MEMBER` field of `Q_PROPERTY`, it doesn't work in Qt 4, but it shows that things get nicer in Qt 5.1 :)

```
#include <QWidget>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPropertyAnimation>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QPainter>

#define PropType uint
class Window: public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(PropType animProp MEMBER m_animProp NOTIFY animPropChanged)
    PropType m_animProp;
public:
    Window();
    Q_SIGNAL void animPropChanged();
protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *);
};

Window::Window()
{
    QPropertyAnimation * anim = new QPropertyAnimation(this, "animProp");
    anim->setDuration( 1000 * 4 );
    anim->setStartValue( 0 );
    anim->setEndValue( 90*100 );
    anim->setLoopCount(-1);

    QPushButton * btn = new QPushButton("Start", this);
    btn->move(20, 20);

    connect(btn, SIGNAL(clicked()), anim, SLOT(start()));
    connect(btn, SIGNAL(clicked()), btn, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    connect(this, SIGNAL(animPropChanged()), SLOT(update()));
}

void Window::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    QPainter p(this);
    p.rotate(m_animProp/100.0);
    p.drawLine(0, 0, width()+height(), 0);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    Window w;
    w.show();
    return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: another question: does QPropertyAnimation use main event loop to generate its events? Does QPropertyAnimation cheaper in terms of eating main-event-loop-CPU time?

Comment: It uses the main event loop, although you are completely free to push it to a different QThread using `moveToThread`. It would not help, it won't make any sense, it may make things worse due to context switch costs. `QPropertyAnimation`'s job is very, very simple. It runs maybe for a microsecond, maybe less. As for if it's cheaper: cheaper than *what*?